# Why apply(type) get inconsistent results in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I created a dataframe, and call apply(type) / applymap(type) in different ways. The problem is that I got different results. I'm confused about the `int` and `int64` types.

```
In [116]: df_term[0:5]
Out[116]: 
                    term    tag  count  weight          pt
0                    -03  OTHER    380  3085.0  2017-12-06
1                   -300    NUM   1224  6120.0  2017-12-06
2                   -805  OTHER     30   258.0  2017-12-06
3  0-150mm0-200mm0-300mm     XH     27  1650.0  2017-12-06
4                 040639  OTHER     52   464.0  2017-12-06

In [106]: df_term.dtypes
Out[106]: 
term       object
tag        object
count       int64
weight    float64
pt         object
dtype: object

In [109]: type(df_term.iloc[0]['count'])
Out[109]: numpy.int64

In [111]: df_term.iloc[0].apply(type)['count']
Out[111]: numpy.int64

In [113]: type(df_term['count'].iloc[0])
Out[113]: numpy.int64

In [114]: df_term['count'].apply(type)[0]
Out[114]: int

In [115]: df_term[0:1].applymap(type)['count']
Out[115]: 
0    <type 'int'>
Name: count, dtype: object
```

I also tried to compare their types:

```
In [156]: df_term.iloc[0].apply(type)['count']
Out[156]: numpy.int64

In [157]: df_term.applymap(type).iloc[0]['count']
Out[157]: int

In [158]: df_term.iloc[0].apply(type)['count'] == df_term.applymap(type).iloc[0]['count']
Out[158]: False
```

Comment: Can you paste the first 5 rows of `df_term`?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ, I have pasted its content

Comment: Ah, things are pretty clear now. There's a difference between what `pandas` displays, and what IPython shows you. But they're both the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider a simple example -

```
In [13]: x = 5

In [14]: type(x)
Out[14]: int

In [15]: repr(type(x))
Out[15]: "<class 'int'>"
```

This first output is IPython's prettification of what `type` returns. The second output is the `__repr__` of the same output, and is what pandas shows you.

Essentially, they're both the same thing. You can see `IPython`'s pretty-printer in action by explicitly importing it from `IPython.lib` -

```
s = pd.Series([1, 2, 3, 4])
s.apply(type)

0    <class 'int'>
1    <class 'int'>
2    <class 'int'>
3    <class 'int'>
dtype: object
```

```
from IPython.lib.pretty import pretty

for r in s.apply(type):
     print(pretty(r))

int
int
int
int
```

---

Regarding the difference between `int` and `np.int64` being displayed, consider -

```
In [16]: df.loc[0, 'count']
Out[16]: 380

In [17]: type(df.loc[0, 'count'])
Out[17]: numpy.int64

In [18]: type(df.loc[0, 'count'].item())
Out[18]: int
```

The data is, by default, loaded into dataframe columns as `np` objects. Accessing a particular element by index will always return the numpy object, which you can then cast to a python object by calling `.item()` on the numpy object. My belief is `apply` implicitly does something like this inside `Series.apply`, in order to pass the value at each row to to the function that `apply` receives (`type` in this case, which is why you see `<class 'int'>` and not `<class 'np.int64'>`.

Comment: I tried to compare those types, and they are not equal.

Comment: @moshangcheng Right, so my guess regarding the difference is that, data is loaded into pandas columns as numpy objects by default (for performance reasons). If you did `df.loc[0, 'count']` you'd see that a `int64` object is returned. Now, call `df.loc[0, 'count'].item()`, and an _int_ object is returned. My guess is that apply implicitly does something like this, passing an item to `type` inside the apply body.